# Is there a way to get a zipped/smaller version of World Of Warcraft?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I JUST bought the game last night online. To my surprise...it's going to take 28GB total download to install... My Internet usage is capped at 14.5 GB a month. Is there a way to get the game installed on my computer without using this much data?? I don't know anyone else personally who plays.

Comment: I dont want to be a dick, but with a data cap that low you really should do more research about games before you buy them, especially for file size. Games go over the 30 GB mark pretty often these days.

Comment: Yeah... point taken. I didn't think that through very well... I used to have WOW many years ago and had an Unlimited connection at that time. It never occurred to me that the file was that large until it began to install. So... here I am trying to salvage my little 20 bucks because I'd like to play the game. Thanks for the helpful comment :) XD

Comment: You can download a crude version World of Warcraft which contains basic gam logic and texture but not the world. It will require to download the world while you walk throu it but you will not have access to cool effects or high graphic quality. WoW downloads this version automatically in the normal download process. You'll see a "Playable" mark at about 1/6 of the loading bar. You can pause the download and play but the game will not look very good

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only official way to get a physical copy of World of Warcraft is to purchase a copy from your local game retailer.

This will also upgrade you to the paid version of the game, if you are playing the starter pack, and should cost around $20, depending on where you live.

World of Warcraft is a large game. But you should not require the entire download to play. At around 5 Gbs, you should get away with starting a character, and playing through as normal. Theres a lot of content players wont experience until further in the game, so the client focuses on content closer to the player, first. This allows you to start playing, even without a fully downloaded game.

If all else fails, take a 32 Gb USB flash stick into your nearest gaming internet cafe, and politely ask them if they can give you a copy of the game. IIRC, the WoW directory should work the same, straight off a USB, and since the client is free to distribute, they should have no issues making you a copy.

Comment: 1. I just re-installed it from scratch a few days ago, and, to my surprise it became playable **very** early. Sure, my connection is quite fast, but it was likely much earlier than 5GB. Oh, you said Gb. I you meant bits then yes, it might be.

Comment: 2. while questing, keep in mind that some models will take a while to load, I once was attacked by a pack of invisible tigers, and they stayed invisible for minutes… still not a huge deal, once you learn how to target them (`r`?), and as long as you don't wander in high-level areas (which you shouldn't do anyway).

Answer (score 2):

If the bandwidth cap is your big concern, then I don't think so. Even a physical copy purchased is going to download a decade's worth of content updates, and even if you start the game when it hits "playable" stage it will continue to try to download in the background while you play. Your only way around would be to copy someone's folder who has already completed download.

Comment: BattleNet-Client features a "Pause Download" Button

Comment: Also an option that tells it specifically not to download anything in the background